# Move content table from iframe to another table outside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I would like to move content of the table in iframe to another table outside iframe and vice versa, just clicking on checkbox.

I have page1.html and page2.html

Here the first code without iframe

```
<table border="1px" id="list1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">List</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th >n&ordm</th>
        <th >Product</th>       
    </tr>
</thead>
```

```
<table border="1px" id="stock">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Stock</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>n&ordm</th>
        <th>Product</th>      
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="nnumber"  />1</td>
        <td>Mouse</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="nnumber"  />2</td>
        <td>Keyboard</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="nnumber"  />3</td>
        <td>Webcam</td>     
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var var1 = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
 var list1 = document.querySelector("#list1 tbody");
 var stock = document.querySelector("#stock tbody");
 var clickOnClick = function () {
 var list = this.checked ? list1 : stock;
 list.appendChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
 };
 for (var indice in var1) {
 var1[indice].onclick = clickOnClick;
 }
 </script>
```

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxiLv.png)

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If `page1.html` and `page2.html` share a common domain such as `example.com/page1.html` and `example.com/page2.html`, then you can access to the page is in the iframe from the other page on which iframe resides. Otherwise you are not allowed access by the browser for security precautions.
You can refer to following example code. You can see in the example that browser is not allowed to access the iframe's contents because of cross-origin security precautions.

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById("frame");
var content = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument);
var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
h1.innerText = "Iframe Test";

content.window.document.body.appendChild(h1);
```

```html
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
```